# Having trouble getting the correct dates from a table

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I currently have this query with the date range set to only the 24th of February. Unfortunately my results have dates from all over the place.

Any direction as to why this is happening?

P.S. "TIMESTAMP" is the name of my column (I can't change this).

```
SELECT
  DATE(TIMESTAMP) as dateofEvent,
  eventType,
  parameters.name,
  parameters.value,
  membershipStatus,
  gender,
  COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE(myFirstTable, TIMESTAMP('2016-02-24 00:00:00'), TIMESTAMP('2016-02-24 23:59:59'))) AS EV
JOIN
  mySecondTable AS UD
ON
  UD.userId = EV.userId
WHERE
  eventType = 'SettingUpdated'
 and (UPPER(parameters.value) = 'TRUE' or UPPER(parameters.value) = 'FALSE')

GROUP BY
  dateofEvent,
  eventType,
  gender,
  parameters.value,
  parameters.name,
  membershipStatus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TABLE_DATE_RANGE` filters **table names**, it does nothing with field values.

So if you want to get only fields in specific time range, you have to make sure the field values correspond to table names. In specific case, you need to make sure to add only rows with `TIMESTAMP` field between '2016-02-24 00:00:00' and '2016-02-24 23:59:59' to the table myFirstTable.20160224. You likely have this violated and the table myFirstTable.20160224 contains `TIMESTAMP` fields all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

When you use below query

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(myFirstTable, 
         TIMESTAMP('2016-02-24 00:00:00'), 
         TIMESTAMP('2016-02-24 23:59:59'))) AS EV
```

FROM statement is being "translated" and you query is executed as if it were like below (see more in [Table wildcard functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions))

```
SELECT *
FROM myFirstTable20160224
```

So, now the fact that you are getting dates all over the place tells me that you have your timestamp field not limited to the 2016-02-24 but rather being all over the place despite table name

If you need to filter output by date you can add something like

```
WHERE DATE(timestamp) = '2016-02-24'
```